# Discord Music Bot not queueing songs (nextcord)

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

My bots doesn't queue the songs when i use the play command, it just plays them. Im trying to get all my commands to work before using spotify & soundcloud in the bot.So, when i use the play command & I try to queue the songs, I cannot queue them. So, can anyone help me ? I have checked the wavelink doc but I couldn't find anything.. (im a beginner with this library)

Code:

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
import wavelink 
import random 
import datetime 
from datetime import datetime
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">")






@bot.event
async def on_wavelink_track_end(player:wavelink.Player,track:wavelink.Track,reason):
  ctx = player.ctx
  vc: player = ctx.voice_client
  
  if vc.loop:
    return await vc.play(track)

  next_song = vc.queue.get()
  await vc.play(next_song)
  emb = nextcord.Embed(description=f"Now playing {next_song.title}",color=nextcord.Color.magenta())
  emb.set_image(url=next_song.thumbnail)
  await ctx.send(embed=emb)   
  


@bot.command(aliases=["p"])
async def play(ctx,*,search:wavelink.YouTubeTrack):
  if not ctx.voice_client:
    vc: wavelink.Player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
  elif not getattr(ctx.author.voice,"channel",None):
    embed=nextcord.Embed(description=f"{ctx.author.mention}: No song(s) are playing.",color=nextcord.Color.blue())
    return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

  
  
  else:
    vc:wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
  if vc.queue.is_empty and vc.is_playing:
   await vc.play(search)
   embe = nextcord.Embed(description=f"Now playing [{search.title}]({search.uri}) ",color=nextcord.Color.magenta())
  
   embe.set_image(url=search.thumbnail)
   await ctx.send(embed=embe)
  else:
    await vc.queue.put_wait(search)
    emb = nextcord.Embed(description=f"Added [{search.title}]({search.uri}) to the queue.",color=nextcord.Color.magenta())
  
    emb.set_image(url=search.thumbnail)
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
  vc.ctx = ctx
  setattr(vc,"loop",False)
  


    
@bot.command()
async def queue(ctx):
  if not ctx.voice_client:
    vc: wavelink.Player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
  elif not getattr(ctx.author.voice,"channel",None):
    embed=nextcord.Embed(description=f"{ctx.author.mention}: No song(s) are playing.",color=nextcord.Color.blue())
    return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  
  else:  
     vc:wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client

  if vc.queue.is_empty:
    emb = nextcord.Embed(description=f"{ctx.author.mention}: The queue is empty. Try adding songs.",color=nextcord.Color.red())
    return await ctx.send(embed=emb)
  lp = nextcord.Embed(title="Queue",color=nextcord.Color.blue())
  queue = vc.queue.copy()
  song_count = 0
  for song in queue:
    song_count += 1
    lp.add_field(name=f"[{song_count}] Song",value=f"{song.title}")
    return await ctx.send(embed=lp)




  

bot.run("TOKEN IS HERE JUST NOT LEAKING IT")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Solved-Music/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nextcord/client.py", line 417, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 181, in on_wavelink_track_end
    song_count += 1
  File "/home/runner/Solved-Music/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wavelink/queue.py", line 212, in get
    raise QueueEmpty("No items in the queue.")
wavelink.errors.QueueEmpty: No items in the queue.
```

Comment: Hey zzeua, please trim your code down to a [mcve]. This will help others better understand your question and assist you more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your code: `vc:wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client if vc.queue.is_empty and vc.is_playing:` to the code `vc:wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client if vc.queue.is_empty and **not** vc.is_playing:`

Answer (score 0):

if you follow the other advice and add a not to the statement.

```
if vc.queue.is_empty and not vc.is_playing:
   await vc.play(search)
```

on my system the bot would load add a song to que and skip

```
await vc.play(search)
```

it turns out forwhat ever reason my system and the function: is_playing dont play nice together.

```
is_playing
```

always returned true thus skipping the line

```
await vc.play(search)
```

if you are having the same issue you can try:

```
if vc.queue.is_empty and vc.is_connected and vc._source is None:

    await vc.play(search)
```

now your bot will play when using the play command and it will queue future songs.